# Pick displayid and displayorder wherever columnname is 1 and delete it, and rearrange the display order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

[image]

I need to pick `displayid` and `displayorder` wherever `columnname` is 1 and delete it, and rearrange the display order

[image]

[image]

I've framed query to delete the `columnid` and rearrange the `displayorder` but didn't know how to traverse through `displayid` using while.?

Comment: _rearrange the display order_? Why?

Comment: Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Thats my need. I'm displaying these columns in my report. so if columnid 1 in displayid 23 has displayorder 1. after deleting columnid1, i don want the rest of columns in displayid 23 to display from order one again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `delete ... from ... join ...` syntax to do the deletion:

```
delete di
from displaytable di
inner join detailstable de 
    on  de.column_id = di.column_id
    and de.columnname = 'one'
```

Then you can reassign new `displayorder`s using `row_number()` and a common table expression:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        di.*,
        row_number() over(partition by displayid order by displayorder) rn
    from displaytable di
)
update cte set displayorder = rn
```

Comment: Nope. I'm not getting the right answer. what if my columnid of display table is not arranged?@GMB

Comment: @user9208802: ok, in this case you could change `row_number() over(partition by displayid order by columnid) rn` to `row_number() over(partition by displayid order by displayorder) rn`

Comment: Hi @GMB, I don't want to update the whole table, There can be few displayids where it doesn't have columnid 1. I want to update only the modified display ids 's displayorder

Comment: @user9208802: for this you can simply add a where clause at the end of the query: `where displayorder != rn`